# How do I slow API calls for Binance API

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, binance, rate-limiting

What must I add to my code so I stop running into API rate limit errors? I believe I run into this error because my script is making to many API calls to the Binance servers.

My code is:

```
from binance.client import Client
client = Client(api_key=***, api_secret=***, tld='us')
```

The client module below uses the requests library. The Client constructor has an optional parameter: `requests_params=None`  and allows you to add a "Dictionary of requests params to use for all calls" (quote from documentation.)

I have looked through the *requests* documentation but could not find anything to fix this issue. I found another library called *ratelimit* but I do not know how to pass it through client() effectively.

The error message I receive is:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.us', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/ping (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

Comment: Can also look at https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/, similar to the decorator example given below just with many more options in the package

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a delay using `time.sleep` in between your requests.

```
from time import sleep

# Adds a delay of 3 seconds
sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a decorator? In my opinion a very clean and beautiful way for your problem :-)

Here an example:

```
import requests
from functools import wraps
import time

def delay(sleep_time:int):
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            print(f"Sleeping {sleep_time} seconds")
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@delay(5)
def get_data(url:str) -> requests.models.Response:
    return requests.get(url)

while True:
    print(get_data("https://www.google.com"))
```